# Distributions of eigenvalues of random matrices: what can they be used for in data mining?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, data-mining, eigenvalues, covariance-matrix

I've accidentally come across some papers discussing distributions of principal components of the sample covariance matrices. An example of such a paper is [Johnstone, 2001, On the distribution of the largest eigenvalue in principal components analysis](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1009210544).

Not to mention that the distribution seems quite complicated (as expected), but even if we know this distribution -- how can we use it in our data mining process?

Comment: +1. Johnstone's result can be used to do a significance test: if the PC1 variance is high enough then we can reject the null hypothesis that the data are random. This is similar to what is known as "parallel analysis". In practice, people are often reluctant to rely on the normality assumption and perform some nonparametric shuffling procedure instead.

Comment: I guess I could provide an answer illustrating what I said above, but it would require some work; let me know if this is interesting of if you had something else in mind. Also, I slightly edited your question, please check that everything is correct.

Comment: Hi tanks for the answer -- but would you explain a bit more before working to provide a formal answer, that what do you mean by the data is "random"?

Comment: Also, is that the main use of the principal component's distribution? Personally though Im not sure exactly what you mean by “random", I think there are other much easier ways to test if data is random...

Comment: Imagine a dataset with 10 variables and 100 data points. You compute correlation matrix and perform PCA. You find out that the first PC explains 15% of the variance. Is it "significant"? What number would you expect if your 100*10 dataset was randomly generated with all variables being uncorrelated? With very large number of data points, all sample correlations would be tiny, so PC1 would explain ~1/10*100% = 10% of the variance. But with only 100 data points you will get some nonzero sample correlations due to chance variations and PC1 will explain more variance. Is 15% higher than that?

Comment: As I said, I doubt anybody ever uses these distributional results in actual data mining. But if you are asking how then can be used, then that's how.

Comment: Thx for your comment. However I think to test if the data are correlated -- Im sure this is a well-studied area and there are many more easier ways to do that...

Comment: and yeah I was looking for some real example on how this can be applied. Afte all, the original paper has more than one thousand citation...

Comment: I don't think it is that easy: among 10 variables there are 45 pairs; of course one test each for significance, but that's a complicated multiple comparisons problem with non-independent tests. Apart from that, the idea is not to test it to get a yes/no answer. The idea is that you want to do PCA and use the leading PCs for some other purpose; the question is if they can be trusted at all. Anyway, I will leave it here.

Comment: I see thank you very much for your input. However to be honest I was more of looking for some other kind of application. Anyway thank you for your effort again.